# Unable to link web domain from godaddy to website

Tags: nginx

I have build a website with node.js + react and deployed it to a CentOs server. I have used nginx for reverse proxy and now the website is working fine and is it accessible at his IP address. i have also added in nginx.conf:

> `server_name www.mydomain.fr`

For the domain i have bought one from GoDaddy. In the DNS management i've added the IP address of the website as an A record but i can not achieve that the website will work with my domain. I have also added in godaddy panel the nameservers of my webhosting provider.
Since is my first deploy i have no much experience with deploying apps any advice would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by restoring godaddy's names servers but this did not fixed the problem. They had some issues on their end that's why it did not worked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have changed name server,  A name that you have set on GoDaddy willl not work because your website hosting provider is managing your dns not the godaddy.

Do one thing

since you have changed the name server you have 2 options.

1. restore name server to godaddy's name server . ( there must be option on ui )
2. login to your new name server provider and they must be having a dns management portal .
   set a name record there pointing to your ip address.

After this , it should work just fine.

Comment: I have removed all my hosting provider nameservers from the godaddy cpanel. hopefully this will work. After my A record in godaddy's cpanel is also added an CNAME record, which points to @ should i remove it too?

Comment: c name is okay. this will not cause an issue . also in your nginx config , change the name to yourdomain.com else add a record for www also in dns portal with A name pointing to your host

Comment: I did added in my nginx.conf file without www too but i had this configuration the entire moth of May and it did not worked. Hopefully it does now...

Comment: this will work . I've used it mutiple times. or you can simply change `server_name www.mydomain.fr` to `server_name 0.0.0.0` to allow all hostnames for testing along with port

Comment: It did not work, my domain is still not connected with my website. Maybe there are some configuration on my webserver to make...

Comment: please share the complete setup you have ( you can use private messaging feature of this if it's somewhat sensitive ) .